# How can i extract day of week from timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a timestamp column in a dataframe as below, and I want to create another column called `day of week` from that. How can do it?

Input:

```
Pickup date/time    
07/05/2018 09:28:00                     
14/05/2018 17:00:00                      
15/05/2018 17:00:00                      
15/05/2018 17:00:00                     
23/06/2018 17:00:00                     
29/06/2018 17:00:00
```

Expected Output:

```
Pickup date/time      Day of Week
07/05/2018 09:28:00     Monday                
14/05/2018 17:00:00     Monday                  
15/05/2018 17:00:00     Tuesday                 
15/05/2018 17:00:00     Tuesday               
23/06/2018 17:00:00     Saturday              
29/06/2018 17:00:00     Friday
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use weekday_name

```
df['date/time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date/time'], format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

df['Day of Week'] = df['date/time'].dt.weekday_name
```

You get

```
    date/time   Day of Week
0   2018-05-07 09:28:00 Monday
1   2018-05-14 17:00:00 Monday
2   2018-05-15 17:00:00 Tuesday
3   2018-05-15 17:00:00 Tuesday
4   2018-06-23 17:00:00 Saturday
5   2018-06-29 17:00:00 Friday
```

Edit:

For the newer versions of Pandas, use day_name(),

```
df['Day of Week'] = df['date/time'].dt.day_name()
```

Comment: I think in Python 3 `weekday_name` is deprecated and you need to use `day_name()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

#### `pandas>=0.23.0`: `pandas.Timestamp.day_name()`

```
df['Day of Week'] = df['date/time'].day_name()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.day_name.html

#### `pandas>=0.18.1,<0.23.0`: `pandas.Timestamp.weekday_name()`

> Deprecated since version 0.23.0

https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.weekday_name.html